# %in% operator vs ==, handling of NA's

Tags: r

I was wondering whats wrong with my code and found that the reason for my odd results was this unexpected handling of NA's by `==` and `%in%`.

```
> NA %in% NA
[1] TRUE
> NA == NA
[1] NA
```

Is there a reason for this? I've been reading about the `==` operator and its handling of `NA`'s but couldn't find any information on why the `%in%` operator handles NA's differently.

Comment: You can't test for `NA` with `==`. You have to use `is.na()`.

Comment: Also, the documentation for `match` (which is how `%in%` is defined) states: "Exactly what matches what is to some extent a matter of definition. For all types, NA matches NA and no other value. For real and complex values, NaN values are regarded as matching any other NaN value, but not matching NA."

Comment: thank you, that makes sense! also i didn't know that %in% is based on match(), hence i failed to do my own research properly.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, using quotes with `?` will get documentation for operators eg: `?"%in%"`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `NA` documentation using `?"=="`, it states that "*Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA.* "

Note also that you can use the identical function i.e. `identical(NA,NA)`